# Configurar acción click de un <a> que se encuentra en un <button>

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, botón

He diseñado unas tarjeta que representan un mensaje, esta tarjeta es un botón con varios componentes más, uno de ellos es un `<a>` que actúa como botón.

El código sería así:

```
<button id="message" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="getMessage('{{ $message -> id }}', '{{ $type_user }}')">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="top" class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <p>{{ $message -> text }}</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-secundary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" title="Eliminar mensaje"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El problema es que al "clickar" sobre el `<a>`, muestra correctamente el `modal` (que es una "PopUp" de "boostrap") pero también se ejecuta el método `onclick` del botón que lo contiene.

¿Alguien podría decirme si hay alguna forma de evitar que esto ocurra?

Comment: El tooltip se deberia mostrar sin tener que pulsar el botón. Deja el ratón sobre la imagen de la basura y espera al tooltip... si no se muestra es que algo has definido para que no se muestre o bien no lo has activado correctamente (los tooltips no estan activos por defecto, deben activarse antes de usarse)

Comment: Puedes evitar la propagación del evento `onclick` hacia el padre colocando en el hijo `onclick="event.stopPropagation()"`. De cualquier manera como menciona @masterguru el tooltip se deberia mostrar sin tener que pulsar el botón.

Comment: Perdona @masterguru, quería expresar `modal` y no se porque he puesto lo de `tooltip`, ahora mismo edito la pregunta, el `tooltip` funciona correctamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias @JaimeMenéndez, tu sugerencia ha funcionado perfectamente.

Comment: De nada @FranCámara. Lo agregué como respuesta para futuras referencias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar la propagación del evento `click` al elemento padre utiliza el método [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) de la interfaz `Event`. Para ello simplemente agrega `onclick="event.stopPropagation()"` al elemento hijo para que no dispare el evento en el padre.